# Spring Security 3.0.5 Concurrency is not working

Tags: spring, security, concurrency

Hi I am using Spring Security 3.0.5 with Spring Framework 3.0.6.  I have configured concurrency as per the documentation.  It is not working.  I login to the application from a browser session and then attemp to login again from another tab in the same browser - it lets me log in instead of denying the attempt.

Here is my security config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
    access-denied-page="/jsp/accessDenied.jsp" 
    entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout.htm"
            logout-success-url="/login.jsp?loggedout=true"/>
        <custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" 
            position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
        <custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" 
            position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER"/>
        <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/> 
</http>

<beans:bean id="authenticationFilter" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
       <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/> 
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp?authfailed=true"/>
</beans:bean>    
<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.jsp" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"  
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">   
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp"/> 
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"
        id="passwordEncoder"/>
<user-service id="userDetailsService">
        <user name="username" password="ee11cbb19052e40b07aac0ca060c23ee"
            authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <user name="test" password="21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3"
            authorities="ROLE_USER" />
</user-service>
<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"/>    
    <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/login.jsp?loggedout=true" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="sas" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />    
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" 
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>Spring security web application (series)</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!--
    - Loads the root application context of this web app at startup. - The
    application context is then available via -
    WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext).
-->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>springsecuritywebapp</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springsecuritywebapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Regards,
Nazir

Comment: All tabs in the same browser get the same session. I tried your code and if I try logging in from different browsers, it invalidates my first session. I can forward the user to a custom page in that case saying "your session is invalid as you have logged on from a different..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />` to `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` bean definition. It will throw exception if allowed sessions are exceeded.

This will have a side effects. Suppose user logged in a browser and close the browser which clears session data. Then the user has to wait for session in server to expire before allowed to login  again.I prefer your existing configuration to this unless you have explicit requirement.

Comment: I did what you said. It still does not work.  Now my securityconfig file looks like the below:

Comment: I ran through the source code. There is no reason it should not work. Check documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-session-mgmt. It clearly says setting the property will not allow login if maximum sessions exceeded.

Comment: Also this http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html